# How to take input from user and store it in array until the user enters a specific word

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I want to create a 2D array with the help of user input but the user do not specifies the length of the array. The input taken from the user should be saved in a 2D array. until the user inputs "FINISH".

I tried using ArrayList but thats too compliciated. Any simple logic to make things work?

Comment: Well, if you don't  know the size of the array in advance, a `Collection`, such as a `List`, is normally used. If you refuse to do that, then you might try an array  set to a size that will be larger than realistically needed. After the inputs are finished, the unused part of the array is trimmed by copying it to an array of the correct length.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Questions are generally expected to show an attempt to solve the problem. Please see the [Tour](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=stackoverflow.com+tour), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and other links in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).  It might also help to search StackOverflow for similar questions.

Comment: Or in the case of a fixed sized array, you keep a separate counter that is used to determine what portion of the fixed array is actually holding values. You just ignore the rest of the unused array.